# Visual Studio 2017 - Problem synchronizing project to Github repository

Tags: visual-studio, github, visual-studio-2017

So i'm trying to add an ASP.NET MVC project to a Github repository through Visual Studio. I've been following this tutorial for guidance: https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/step-by-step-setup-git-version-control-with-net-project-and/

However, after reaching Step 8, all i have in my repository are the ".gitignore" and ".gitattribute" files. And this was the output i received in my console:

```
A new Git repository has been created for you in C:\Users\User1\source\repos\Candidaturas.
Opening repositories:
C:\Users\User1\source\repos\Candidaturas
Opening repositories:
C:\Users\User1\source\repos\Candidaturas
The calling thread cannot access this object because a different thread owns it.
```

Comment: Are your files opened somewhere else?

Comment: Nope. Only on Visual Studio 2017.

Comment: So after clicking "Source Control -> Commit" (with right mouse button on the project), commiting the whole project and clicking "Sync", all my project files were synchronized correctly.

Answer (score -1):

in the first time you should login to your github account by your email and password you will find pop up window to login see this photo to clear
[visual studio image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/imRnV.png)